# ExtJS TreeGrid's Node mouseover event

Tags: extjs, javascript

I have googled and didn't find anything for extjs TreeGrid's mouseover event example. I tried

```
exTree.on('mouseover', function(node,event){
    alert(1)
},this );
```

but it is not working. I have tried this one as well inside the listeners:

```
listeners: {
    'mouseover': function(node, event) {
        alert(1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you tried solutions provided [here](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?23479-TreeNode-mouseover-event)? there are at least 2 working examples

Comment: wondering if you can help me out?  :-)  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9058921/configuration-required-to-get-sencha-extjs-treegrid-example-working